# Decrypt API response to string

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, encryption, rncryptor

```
let dd = aaa.value(forKey: "secret_key") as! String
let data = dd.data(using: .utf8)
let decryptedData = try? RNCryptor.decrypt(data: data, withPassword: password)
print(decryptedData)
```

I am using RNCryptor to convert encrypted data in response of service calls. I am getting the response as string . How can i decrypt the string response using RNCryptor. By using the above code, I am getting nil value.

Comment: Why do you ignore a possible error with `try?` ? Maybe the error tells you what's wrong.

Comment: Instead of using `try?`, you should using the `do-try-catch` for catch the error

Comment: I tried that. There is no error. I am getting nil value . I think the problem is I am getting string from API response . Encrypted value is in string format

Comment: you are passing string to `decrypt` method, it should be `Data`.

Comment: still i am not getting. I have editted my question

Comment: Is the data you're decrypted in the RNCryptor format? RNCryptor is not a general-purpose cryptography library. It supports a specific format. (In the above code, `data` is definitely not RNCryptor-data, because there's no way to generate that from `data(using: .utf8)`.)